# Find the number of roots of $z^5+4z^2+z+1$ in $1\leq|z|\leq 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

> Find the number of roots of $z^5+4z^2+z+1$ for $1\leq|z|\leq 2$

Using Rouché's theorem, I showed that it has $3$ roots in the annulus counting multiplicities. So I have to rule out that any of the roots repeat. This is equivalent to show the polynomial is separable, which can be showed by showing the gcd of it and its derivative is $1$. However, that is not easy as it is equivalent to showing they do not have roots in common. A solution I came up with is the following. We know one root is real and by IVT, it is between $-2$ and $1$, so it is in the annulus. Now the other roots are conjugate and so unless they are real, they cannot be double roots. I am not sure how to show the roots are not real.

What is the standard way of showing a polynomial is separable over an algebraically closed field?

Comment: What is the gcd of this polynomial and its derivate?

Comment: @miracle173 It is $1$. but i know that only because I know the function is separable.

Comment: You can  calculate the gcd by using the Euclidian Algorithm for polynomials

Comment: The real root is between $-2$ and $-1$ by inspection

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici there could be 2 more real roots, no?

Comment: No; four complex roots

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I know that because i graphed the function. How would I be able to tell without a computer?

Comment: Stop graphing things, and worrying about real and complex roots, etc. Miracle173 already gave you the correct answer. The GCD of two polynomials over any field can be computed (by elementary means) without knowing **anything** about the roots. Compute the GCD directly using Euclidean division to show it's 1 (or. to be pedantic, it's a "unit" of **C** [z]).